# How does the MX record really work?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, email-server, mx-record

So say I have the domain example.com and I want to send and receive e-mails over that domain, then I use the MX record to point to a mail server. If I set the MX records to gmail, for example, so:

1- Do I get e-mails sent to whatever@example.com or can I set a specific username(instead of whatever, e.g: admin@example.com) for sending/receiving, and if I do, how do I set that?

2- How do I receive the e-mails sent to Google's mail server after they are sent, do I set up a Gmail account to where the domain's e-mails get forwarded to, or is there another way to get it, and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh my sweet child.

> So say I have the domain example.com and I want to send and receive e-mails over that domain, then I use the MX record to point to a mail server. If I set the MX records to gmail, for example, so:

Whoa there partner, what do you mean by "set the MX records to gmail"? You set your MX records to point to an SMTP server's hostname. That SMTP server ***can*** be Google Apps, if you have a paid Google Apps account. Part of Google apps includes Google Mail. However, I don't think you're talking about Google Apps, because of what you say next:

> Do I get e-mails sent to whatever@example.com or can I set a specific username(instead of whatever, e.g: admin@example.com) for sending/receiving, and if I do, how do I set that?

MX records are sought out by sending SMTP servers, and all email they want to send to your domain is sent to the host represented by the MX record. So if your email server is smtp.example.com, then all email, regardless of the recipient address, is sent to that host's MTA to get handled.*

> How do I receive the e-mails sent to Google's mail server after they are sent, do I set up a Gmail account to where the domain's e-mails get forwarded to, or is there another way to get it, and how?

Heaven help us all. You need to have your own mail server, or pay for a service to receive your mail. Gmail does not come into play *unless you purchase a Google Apps account* which is not "Gmail", strictly, speaking.

Perhaps it's time you stepped back and researched this topic a little deeper so that you can pose more specific questions and receive more specific answers. You are about to embark on a fantastic journey of knowledge, understanding, personal growth, and intense hurting (but the last one should go without saying since we're discussing email, after all).

---

*<sub>Technically yes an MTA can accept email for a domain and then send it on down to a specific email address. However you still have to run your own MTA and then configure it to forward on to a specific mailbox, such as yourname@gmail.com.</sub>

Comment: The answer is correct, it does not have to be condescending.

Comment: yeah the answer is great i dont now who downvoted

Comment: @user3407319 People are over sensitive and silly. So it must have been an over sensitive and silly person who downvoted. Pay them no mind. You however, are a Viking Warlord for staring email in the face and, in spite of what you saw, deciding you wanted to know more about its guts. May your death be epic and honorable, enshrined in stone and surrounded by the flames of your enemies.

Comment: lol..so lets see if i uderstand well i need to pay for the mail server no free gmail service and the second thing is that all emails sent to ...@gmail.com is sent to the smtp server and handled there, is that all right?

Comment: @user3407319 If you own `example.com` you change the MX record to send down to an SMTP server configured to accept email for `example.com`. That could be a server you run. That could be a service like Google Apps. I personally run an `exim` server that accepts email for a lot of domains, and one thing I can do is send the accepted emails down to any single email address I want. You could do the same with a $5 Digital Ocean droplet and a few hours of research into Exim, Postfix, qmail, or your MTA of choice. Or just pay for Google Apps, as an example of a paid service.

Comment: @user3407319 Also, if you upvote the answer as well as accept it, it'll cancel out the silly downvote. :D

Comment: I didn't find this answer to be condescending in the slightest. The OP wasn't personally disparaged or condescended to. Simply a little humor mixed in with some needed insight and guidance.

Comment: @Wesley i just have one more question i was wondering about, I installed hmailserver on my pc and i want to point the mx record of example.com to point to my pc(which is now a mail server), how do i set that, n.b: i have already tried pointing the mx record to the public ip address of my pc but it didnt work saying that it was invalid content for mx record, so how do i set that up?

Comment: would i set the mx to point to the domain example.com whose a record points to my ip address?

Comment: @user3407319 MX records should be a hostname, and some DNS hosts will enforce that. Others are lax and will let you put an IP address in. Create an A record named mail.example.com that points to your IP address, then make an MX record that points to that A record.